# Scan is already in progress issue with ionic V3 in iOS13

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ios13, barcode-scanner

When click barcode scanner at first time, scanner opening and i didn't scan anything. Instead, i Slide down the barcode scanner in iOS 13 device.When i try to launch the barcode scanner second time i am getting the error **'Scan is already in progress'.**

I am using hybrid mobile application with ionic Version 3 (supported platforms are android and iOS). But issue occur only on iOS.

Please provide your solution to fix the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: ey @Saravanan do you find a solution for this problem? I edited the node_modules file of this plugin like that https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/pull/853, but it is not a final solution because i had to edit that every time that i install the dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem with android.

I solved this issue by delete the android folder and create it again by `npx cap sync`